# How to write intinsic code for this inline assembly code?

Tags: c, simd, inline-assembly, intrinsics

I am not good at SIMD, so, I need the help for converting this code to intrinsic code.
In my opinion, it seems like C = A * B, but I am not sure.
Can anybody help me?
Also I want to ask whether the intrinsic functions are avaiable for mobile processor.
In fact, the code below is for intel CPU, but my work is finally aimed for mobile device. Thanks in advance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++, C += N) {
    float x = A[i];
    _asm {
        mov             esi, N8;
        sub             esi, 8;
        shl             esi, 2;
        xor             edi, edi;
        mov             ebx, B;
        mov             edx, C;
        vbroadcastss    ymm7, x;
    Lrep1:
        cmp             edi, esi;
        jg              Lexit1;
        vmovups         ymm0, ymmword ptr[ebx + edi];
        vmulps          ymm0, ymm0, ymm7;
        vmovups         ymmword ptr[edx + edi], ymm0;
        add             edi, 32;
        jmp             Lrep1;

    Lexit1:
    }
    for (int j = N8; j < N; j++) C[j] = x * B[j];
}
```

Comment: This loop is poorly optimized; it's 6 uops when it could be just 4 or 5.  Also, do you mean a mobile x86 CPU like you'd find in a laptop?  Or do you mean ARM?  Yes there are intrinsics for ARM NEON.  But compilers often do a bad job with NEON intrinsics, unlike x86 where intrinsics get optimized nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be far better off replacing the entire code with just:

```
float x = A[i];
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) C[j] = x * B[j];
```

The compiler will do a far better job of optimising that than the somewhat naive attempt at asm optimisation presented above. Fire your co-worker :)

As for what it's doing, not a whole lot. It's just looping through the floats in batches of 8. As I said though, it's pretty stupid, and you'd be better off from a performance POV of using the standard C code above.

```
float x = A[i];
__m256 _x = _mm256_set1_ps(x);
for (int j = 0; j < N8; j += 8) 
{
  _mm256_storeu_ps(C + j, _mm256_mul_ps(_x, _mm256_loadu_ps(B + j)));
}
for (int j = N8; j < N; j++) C[j] = x * B[j];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I tried the raw code as your recommendation. But it slows down. Is there any compiler optimization switch?

Comment: -mavx2 -mfma -O2 -ffast-math (although be careful of the last one - it may change the precision)

Comment: It really shouldn't be slower. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/agyTp0
Look for the inner loop where it uses the vmulps instructions. Realistically, because the amount of actual CPU work done here is minimal, the code will be limited by memory bandwidth.

Comment: Wonderful answer. One more question. What are they in Visual Studio Project Property Pages?

Comment: When should I use SIMD if the compiler does a far better job of optimising that than the somewhat naive attempt at asm optimisation?

Comment: @hbs Never? Or well, when you look at the assembly code generated by the compiler, and know what's wrong with it (IOW you think you can make it faster), and know that it actually matters. Then you could try writing the better assembly yourself, just remember to benchmark that your code is actually so much faster that you can justify the extra maintenance burden of having hand-tuned assembly code. But also, when you want to do it for fun or learning, and won't actually put it into production...

Comment: rob and @hbs: I would *not* suggest using `-mavx2 -mfma` on their own.  Instead use `-march=znver1` or `-march=skylake -O3` or something to set tuning options as well.  Otherwise GCC will leave `-mtune=generic` enabled so it splits possibly-unaligned 256-bit loads/stores with `vinsertf128`.  [Why doesn't gcc resolve \_mm256\_loadu\_pd as single vmovupd?](//stackoverflow.com/q/52626726).  Clang doesn't do that, and unrolls some by default.  (GCC only unrolls with `-fprofile-generate` / `-fprofile-use` to find hot loops, which you should use if possible.)

Comment: @hbs: Compiling with `-O3 -march=native` *is* using SIMD.  You usually only need to *manually vectorize* in non-trivial loops that don't auto-vectorize easily.  e.g. when there's some shuffling needed inside the loop and the compiler doesn't do it efficiently.